# TypeError: get() got multiple values for argument 'task_id'

Tags: python, django

i have an endpoint that takes an id `task/:task_id/`. but when i try to access the id in the endpoint i get this error. `TypeError: get() got multiple values for argument 'task_id'`

i tried to give task_id parameter a none default value.

```py
from huey.contrib.djhuey import HUEY
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class TaskStatus(APIView):
    def get(self, task_id):
        return Response({
            'result': Huey.result(task_id)
        })
```

```py
    url(r'tasks/(?P<task_id>[a-f0-9\-]{36})/', TaskStatus.as_view(), name='task-status'),
```

i expect `task_id` to return the id from the url parameter.

Answer (score 18):

The first parameter of `get` must be `request` itself. change the

```
def get(self, task_id):
    ...
```

to this one:

```
def get(self, request, task_id): 
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `get` function is wrong. The reason you get the error message is that there aren't enough parameters for the function since it expects a `request` parameter as well.

Since there's 1 parameter short, the error message occurs because it tries to cramp both `request` and `task_id` into the `task_id` parameter, hence the "multiple values" part of the error message.

This should do the trick.

```
class TaskStatus(APIView):
    def get(self, request, task_id):
        return Response({
            'result': Huey.result(task_id)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(self, task_id):
    pass
```

The error comes because you have more than 2 return results returned and you have only 2 space holders, thus fighting for task_id, and self. add 'request' to reduce this competition of space and now should work.

Your get function requires three arguments(self, request & task_id). Normally in get you might note that request is light colored and think you don't need request. But under the hood, that request is doing it's work even if grayed. request is always the 2nd argument. Now like below, should work.

```
def get(self, request, task_id):
    pass
```

This should now work.